# Helm install gives error while installing jenkins

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm, minikube

While I am trying to install jenkins using Helm chart, it gives error.

```sh
$ helm install --name jenkins --namespace jenkins --values values.yml stable/jenkins
```

> Error: render error in "jenkins/templates/deprecation.yaml": template: jenkins/templates/deprecation.yaml:105:14: executing "jenkins/templates/deprecation.yaml" at : error calling fail: `Master.ServiceType` does no longer exist. It has been renamed to `master.serviceType`

**values.yml**

```
Master:
  ServicePort: 8080
  ServiceType: NodePort
  NodePort: 32123
  ScriptApproval:
    - "method groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic parseText java.lang.String"
    - "new groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic"
    - "staticMethod org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods leftShift java.util.Map java.util.Map"
    - "staticMethod org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods split java.lang.String"
  InstallPlugins:
    - kubernetes:1.7.1   
    - workflow-aggregator:2.5   
    - workflow-job:2.21   
    - credentials-binding:1.16   
    - git:3.9.1   
Agent:
  volumes:
    - type: HostPath
      hostPath: /var/run/docker.sock
      mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock

Persistence:
  enabled: true
  StorageClass: jenkins-volume   
  Size: 3Gi

NetworkPolicy:
  enabled: false
  ApiVersion: extensions/v1beta1

rbac:
  install: true
  serviceAccountName: default
  apiVersion: v1beta1
  roleRef: cluster-admin
```

Comment: It is a version deprecation related to the jenkins version you are running and your k8s cluster. Run `helm search jenkins` and show me the version please.

Comment: ```helm search jenkins```   gives below output
NAME --> stable/jenkins       
CHART VERSION --> 1.7.8 
APP VERSION --> lts
DESCRIPTION -->   Open source continuous integration server. It supports mu...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `values.yaml` file isn't compatible with `jenkins`'s `values.yaml`. You should follow the format they suggest.

```
master:
  servicePort: 8080
  serviceType: NodePort
  nodePort: 32123
  scriptApproval:
    - "method groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic parseText java.lang.String"
    - "new groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic"
    - "staticMethod org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods leftShift java.util.Map java.util.Map"
    - "staticMethod org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods split java.lang.String"
  installPlugins:
    - kubernetes:1.7.1   
    - workflow-aggregator:2.5   
    - workflow-job:2.21   
    - credentials-binding:1.16   
    - git:3.9.1 

  ......
```

You can find the actual format at [jenkins/values.yaml](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/jenkins/values.yaml).